# how to install certificate programmatically on Android without user interaction

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ssl-certificate, vpn

How do I silently install CA Certificates as a device owner,
the installCACert method does not allow me to use the certificate for the VPN profile.

Comment: I'm going to guess that adding a CA to the system without user interaction is not something that can be done (at least not by a unprivileged app) for security reasons (If any old app could do this  then you could be vulnerable to MITM attacks without knowing.